# Error when I use android Selector XML file - No valid attribute of android:color="xxx" ,replacing with an item inside the tag

Tags: android

I get an unexpected error and stopping the app when I use a selector for a list or for some components of a list.I use api 19 kitkat and android studio.
My xml selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true"
    android:color="#0094CE">
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#0094CE">
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#ACD52B">
</item>
</selector>
```

and my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/idFragmentLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="@string/frg_error_request"
tools:context=".fragments.ErrorRequestFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="@string/frg_error_request"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/requestListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_item_background_selector"
        android:listSelector="#0f0">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also I remove android:listselector but it was not effect.What is my mistake in writing of a selector xml file?

Comment: please, detail out the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found: Error point:android:color="xxx" is not valid in run time. I don't know why! if you replace this attribute with  tag inside the item , it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide the selector as background in listView.when we use the selector as background for textView or ListView, its give XML error.  Instead, give this selector as an itemSelector tag in listView. 
 android:listSelector="@drawable/test_drawable"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.Yes the place of background in not suitable but it must not be give us an error! I found error point:android:color="xxx" is not valid in run time I don't know why! if you replace this attribute with <color .. /> tag inside the item , it works fine. However many thanks for your reply.